# component.find an aura:id item created in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I am building a menu component.

One menu-item is a sub-menu with list of opportunities, this list is created with `aura:iteration` over a list of opportunities.

When selecting a menu or a sub-menu, I need to make it look selected (change css attribute). For this to happen, I need to find this menu item in my controller.

If I add `id` attribute to my item markup and use the event attribute on my controller (`event.currentTarget.id`), I can catch the item itself and change it's style, this works:

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunities}" var="opp">
    <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="{!opp.Id}" onclick="{!c.openItemFromMenu}">
            <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!opp.Name}">{!opp.Name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
openItemFromMenu: function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the id
    var oppId = event.currentTarget.id;
    // choose it (select menu)
    var selectedItemNew = component.find(oppId);
    selectedItemNew.style = "background: rgb(216, 237, 255);"
}
```

**PROBLEM**

when I try to change the menu selected not from the click of the item (event that is triggered from another page) - I have added an event handler to change the menu item, and I send the opportunity id through that event. Then (after adding `aura:id` to my item, I am trying to find this menu item of this oppId with `component.find` in my controller - this does not work:

**CHANGED MARKUP**

```
add:
<aura:handler name="eventSelectMenuItem" event="c:myEvent" action="{!c.openItemFromMenu}" />
change:
<a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="{!opp.Id}" onclick="{!c.openItemFromMenu}" aura:id="{!opp.Id}">
```

**CHANGED CONTROLLER**

```
openItemFromMenu: function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the id from the event
    var oppId = event.getParam("recordId");
    // choose it (select menu)
    var selectedItemNew = component.find(oppId);
    selectedItemNew.style = "background: rgb(216, 237, 255);"
}
```

**QUESTION**

Does `component.find` for `aura:id` within an `aura:iteration` suppose to work?

If not - is there a workaround?

If it does suppose to work - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aura:id` must be a literal value. As such, you can't use an expression in `aura:id` (it will be treated as literal text). Instead, you can use the element's `id` via `document.getElementById`:

```
var selectedItemNew = document.getElementById(oppId);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great, but isn't this a bad practice to use `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: @ItaiShmida Internally, Lightning actually uses a SecureDocument, so you should be okay using getElementById with your own components. You could also use getElementsByTagName or the like as well.

Comment: So this is not something that will be unsupported or locked by locker service or some other excuse in the future?

Comment: @ItaiShmida Correct. Check out the [Locker API Test](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV) page to see supported calls for SecureWindow, SecureDocument, and SecureElement.

Comment: that solution is perfect, but it makes me wonder - if I can use `document.getElementById` - why should I ever use `aura:id`? is there any advantage in using it?

Comment: @ItaiShmida `document.getElementById` retrieves DOM elements. It's also inherently limited to getting just one element, so you need to make sure that the Id is unique within the component. `aura:id` with `component.find` is used to get components, which you'd use to access and modify its attributes and methods. For example, you couldn't use `document.getElementById` on a `lightning:input`.

Answer (score 4):

First problem is that we cannot use expression while assigning aura:id. Aura:id need to be static.

so your first change is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="{!opp.Id}" onclick="{!c.openItemFromMenu}" aura:id="link">
```

in js you can do

```
    openItemFromMenu: function(component, event, helper) {
        // get the id from the event
        var oppId = event.getParam("recordId");
        // choose it (select menu)
        var selectedItemsNew = component.find('link').getElements();
        if(Array.isArray(selectedItemsNew)){
            var selectedItemNew = selectedItemsNew.find(function (oneItem){
return oppId === selectedItemsNew.id})
           if(selectedItemNew){
              selectedItemNew.style = "background: rgb(216, 237, 255);"
           }
        } else if(selectedItemsNew){
          if(oppId === selectedItemsNew.id){
             selectedItemNew.style = "background: rgb(216, 237, 255);"
          }
        }

    }
```

Instead of adding style directly you can create a class and use

> $a.util.addclass()

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will work for you, but what worked for me was just assigning the same static aura:id to each element in the iteration, and then when you use component.find() it will return an array of all the elements.

Comment: Thomas Sesselmann The same is true for me