# How to identify which lightning:fileUpload was clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fileupload

I am using `lightning:fileUpload` multiple times inside `aura:iteration`.

After the button was clicked and the file was uploaded, I am using `onuploadfinished` event to do some stuff, but I need to identify which `lightning:fileUpload` button was clicked and cannot do so.

I cannot use `aura:id` on the `lightning:fileUpload` component because my id is dynamic (from `aura:iteration`) and I need to put literal id [there](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203291/component-find-an-auraid-item-created-in-auraiteration):

I also cannot use `event.currentTarget.id` in the controller because the `onuploadfinished` event has no target and no currentTarget objects so I cannot find the id.

This is my code:

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="files" type="FileWrapper[]" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.files}" var="file">
        <lightning:fileUpload id="{!file.formName}"
                              aura:id="{!file.formName}"
                              label="Upload a new file"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {

        // get the aura:id
        var auraId = event.getSource().getLocalId();    // returns "{!file.formName}"

        // get the id
        var currentTarget = event.currentTarget;    // returns null
        var target = event.target;  // returns null
        var id = currentTarget.id;  
        // now do some stuff
    }
})
```

**QUESTION**

How can I use multiple `lightning:fileUpload` components in an iteration and uniquely identify which one was pressed?

Comment: Why do you have multiple file upload components?

Comment: @glls Each upload button uploads a different type of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using aura:id or Id you can use name attribute of **fileUploadComponent**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="files" type="FileWrapper[]" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.files}" var="file">
        <lightning:fileUpload name="{!file.formName}"
                              label="Upload a new file"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

your JS code will be

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {

        // get the aura:id
        var fileId = event.getSource().get('v.name');    

        // now do some stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: Another trick when dealing with components that need unique-ness, but there's nowhere to store it... You can use `class` attribute to embed some of your dynamic id merges. If you have actual class names you can split by `" "` and then deal with a prefix match then split out the unique identifier within the "class" name.