# How to get values from dynamically created lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

`<aura:iteration items="{!v.userCustomFieldSet}" var="fieldSet" indexVar="i"> 
     <ui:inputText value="{!fieldSet.FieldValue}" aura:id="{!fieldSet.FieldName}"/> 
 </aura:iteration>`

Above code, Getting Error when i'm accessing the field-set 
**Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined**

Comment: You cannot assign auraid’s dynamically

Comment: I think that [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/how-to-use-fieldsets-with-lightning) you can find solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like glls pointed out, dynamic aura:ids are not supported (yet). It will be helpful to know what your end goal is so we can make an effective recommendation. Did you know that if you set the `aura:id` to a static value like: `aura:id="myInput"`, you can get the values in ControllerJS by doing: `component.find("myInput").get("v.value")`? That will work as long as there is precisely ONE matching `aura:id` in the component. But in your case there will be multiple because of `aura:iteration`, so `component.find("myInput")` will return an array of all matching elements you can easily loop through.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in by @glls in the comment and @Kal answer - You cannot assign auraid’s dynamically, instead you can use the element's id via `document.getElementById`:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.userCustomFieldSet}" var="fieldSet" indexVar="i"> 
     <ui:inputText value="{!fieldSet.FieldValue}" id="{!fieldSet.FieldName}"/> 
</aura:iteration>
```

and in you controller get the element like this:

```
var fieldName = document.getElementById('fieldName');
```

I got help on this from an answer that @sfdcfox gave me here:

[component.find an aura:id item created in aura:iteration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203291/component-find-an-auraid-item-created-in-auraiteration)