# Passing iterated variable from Markup to JS Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, indexing

I need a way to keep track of each iterated lightning:inputField so that any changes made to that specific field is reflected by a CSS style change.

*Markup*

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.layoutAPIFieldsList}" var="e" indexVar="i">
       <aura:if isTrue="{!e.APIName != 'requestDocType__c'}">
          <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6"> 
             <lightning:inputField aura:id="{!e.APIName}"
                                   fieldName="{!e.APIName}" 
                                   onchange="{!c.changeInputField}" />
          </lightning:layoutItem>  
      </aura:if>
   </aura:iteration>
```

*JS Controller*

```
changeInputField : function(component, event, helper){  
    var cmpTarget = component.find(/* Iterated Variable */);
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'unsavedChanges');      
},
```

Here in the JS is where I want to pass the iterated variable and apply the CSS.
Maybe I should locate it by index or aura:id?

Comment: I think `event.getSource()` will give you a reference to the component. So you should be able to pass it in to the `addClass()` function?

Comment: Also. Note that aura:id’s cannot be assigned dynamically

Answer (score 0):

As @glls said - `aura:id’s cannot be assigned dynamically`

The solution I have for that (For [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203291/component-find-an-auraid-item-created-in-auraiteration) question and with help of @sfdcfox) is to assign an id to the html element - so you can try in your component markup:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.layoutAPIFieldsList}" var="e" indexVar="i">
   <aura:if isTrue="{!e.APIName != 'requestDocType__c'}">
      <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6"> 
         <lightning:inputField id="{!e.APIName}"
                               fieldName="{!e.APIName}" 
                               onchange="{!c.changeInputField}" />
      </lightning:layoutItem>  
  </aura:if>
```

And then in the js controller:

```
changeInputField : function(component, event, helper){  
    var cmpTarget = document.getElementById(/* Iterated Variable */);
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'unsavedChanges');      
},
```