# Connect two Lightning li elements by line

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm utilizing this [repo](https://github.com/sfdcbox/Kanban-Lightning-component) to create a custom kanban. I'm able to generate a list of tasks in my system but the trouble I'm having is drawing a line to connect two tasks together. The idea is to show continuity of sub-task and super-task.

I've been fiddling with the js controller in function doInit. The data loads and its failing on the line attempting to getBoundingClientRect() of undefined. I understand undefined means it was never initialized but neither option of component.find() or document.getElementById is working. Those are the Ids generated in the HTML by the task records generating.

[image]

Every [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203291/component-find-an-auraid-item-created-in-auraiteration) like this one explains it should be possible with document.getElementById() but so far hasn't. I'm confused why I can't get the list item element reference.

App/Component-parent:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <c:EnhancedKanban objName="Task" objFields="['WhatId', 'WhoId', 'Subject', 'Status', 'Description', 'ActivityDate', 'Priority']" kanbanPicklistField="Status"/>
</aura:component>
```

component:

```
<!-- https://github.com/sfdcbox/Kanban-Lightning-component -->
<aura:component controller="kanbanController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="objName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objFields" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="kanbanPicklistField" type="String"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="kanbanData" type="kanbanController.kanbanWrap"/>

    <div style="padding:0.5rem;">
        <aura:iteration var="pickVal" items="{!v.kanbanData.pickVals}">
            <div class="stageContainer" style="{!'width:calc(100vw/'+(v.kanbanData.pickVals.length+0.5)+')'}">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                    <div>
                        <div class="slds-media slds-no-space slds-has-divider_bottom-space slds-media_center" style="{!'width:calc(100vw/'+(v.kanbanData.pickVals.length+1)+')'}">
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-align-middle slds-truncate" title="{!pickVal}">{!pickVal}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}" class="slds-has-dividers_around-space dropZone" data-Pick-Val="{!pickVal}" style="height:70vh;overflow-y:auto;">
                    <aura:iteration var="objRecord" items="{!v.kanbanData.records}">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!pickVal == objRecord.Status}">
                            <li class="slds-item slds-m-around_small" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="{!objRecord.Id}">
                                <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                                    <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!objRecord.Name}">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.doView}">
                                            <span class="slds-truncate slds-text-heading_medium" id="{!objRecord.Id}">{!objRecord.Subject}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body_small">
                                        <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">{!objRecord.Description}</p>
                                        <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">{!objRecord.ActivityDate}</p>
                                        <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">{!objRecord.Priority}</p>
                                        <!-- <p class="slds-truncate" title="{!objRecord.Account.Name}">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.doView}">
                                                <span class="slds-truncate" id="{!objRecord.AccountId}">{!objRecord.Account.Name}</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </p> -->
                                        <!-- <p class="slds-truncate" title="{!'Closing ' +objRecord.CloseDate}">Closing {!'Closing ' +objRecord.CloseDate}</p> -->
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                        </aura:if> 
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getKanbanWrap");
        action.setParams({
            "objName":component.get("v.objName"),
            "objFields":component.get("v.objFields"),
            "kanbanField":component.get("v.kanbanPicklistField")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.dir(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.kanbanData", response.getReturnValue());

                // ATTEMPT TO CONNECT LINE
                var div1 = document.getElementById('00Tg000000SJbRiEAL'); //component.find('00Tg000000SJbRiEAL'); 
                var div2 = document.getElementById('00Tg000000SJbTLEA1'); //component.find('00Tg000000SJbTLEA1');//

                var rect1 = div1.getBoundingClientRect(); // Fails here: Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined] Callback failed: apex://kanbanController/ACTION$getKanbanWrap
                var rect2 = div2.getBoundingClientRect();

                // bottom right
                var x1 = rect1.left + window.pageXOffset + (rect1.width || div1.offsetWidth);
                var y1 = rect1.top + window.pageYOffset + (rect1.height || div1.offsetHeight);
                // top right
                var x2 = rect2.left + window.pageXOffset + (rect2.width || div2.offsetWidth);
                var y2 = rect2.top + window.pageYOffset + (rect2.height || div2.offsetHeight);
                // distance
                var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
                // center
                var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
                var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (5 / 2);
                // angle
                var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
                // make hr
                var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + 5 + "px; background-color:" + "#0F0" + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
                //
                document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine; 
                // ATTEMPT TO CONNECT LINE
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    doView: function(component, event, helper) {
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": event.target.id
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();
    },
    allowDrop: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    drag: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    },

    drop: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var tar = event.target;
        while(tar.tagName != 'ul' && tar.tagName != 'UL')
            tar = tar.parentElement;
        tar.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaa   :   ' + tar.getAttribute('data-Pick-Val'));
        document.getElementById(data).style.backgroundColor = "#ffb75d";
        helper.updatePickVal(component,data,component.get("v.kanbanPicklistField"),tar.getAttribute('data-Pick-Val'));
    }
})
```

helper

```
({
    updatePickVal : function(component, recId, pField, pVal) {
        //Id recId, String kanbanField, String kanbanNewValue
        var action = component.get("c.getUpdateStage");
        action.setParams({
            "recId":recId,
            "kanbanField":pField,
            "kanbanNewValue":pVal
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                document.getElementById(recId).style.backgroundColor = "#04844b";
                setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById(recId).style.backgroundColor = ""; }, 300);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

kanbanController

```
public class kanbanController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static kanbanWrap getKanbanWrap(String objName, String[] objFields, String kanbanField) {
        List<String> lstPickvals=new List<String>();

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(kanbanField).getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : ple)
        {
            lstPickvals.add(a.getValue());
        }

        System.debug(lstPickvals);

        String query = 'SELECT Id, ';
        for(String s:objFields){
            query += s+' ,';
        }
        query = query.removeEnd(',');
        query += ' FROM ' + objName;
        System.debug('qq  ' + query);

        return new kanbanWrap(Database.query(query), lstPickvals);
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getUpdateStage(Id recId, String kanbanField, String kanbanNewValue) {
        SObject o1 = recId.getSObjectType().newSObject(recId);
        o1.put(kanbanField,kanbanNewValue);
        update o1;
        return 'Success';
    }

    public class kanbanWrap{
        @AuraEnabled
        List<sObject> records {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        List<String> pickVals {get;set;}

        public kanbanWrap(List<sObject> recs, List<String> pVals){
            this.records = recs;
            this.pickVals = pVals;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can not access this div is Rendering Lifecycle.

init => render => afterRender => ... ([Create a Custom Renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm?search_text=afterRender))

You are trying to get elements in time when they haven't been rendered yet.

1. Move `doInit` into helper.
2. Create Renderer.js file in the folder of your component bundle.

```js
({
    afterRender : function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.doInit(component, helper);
    }
})
```

**Working example**

*test.cmp*

```html
<aura:component>
    <canvas id="{!globalId + 'canvas'}"></canvas>
</aura:component>
```

*test.cmp-meta.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuraDefinitionBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <description>test</description>
</AuraDefinitionBundle>
```

*testController.js*

```js
({
})
```

*testHelper.js*

```js
({
    doInit : function(component) {
        let globalId = component.getGlobalId();
        let canvas = document.getElementById(globalId + 'canvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
})
```

*testRenderer.js*

```js
({
    afterRender : function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.doInit(component);
    },

    rerender : function(component, helper){
        this.superRerender();
        helper.doInit(component);
    }
})
```

Comment: it didn't seem to work. Do you have a working example of the questions code above?

Comment: @AlexMiller, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.getElementById` or `Element.innerHTML`. The former won't work because ID values are "mangled" by the framework, and the latter shouldn't be used because it violates Locker Service restrictions. You'll need to use `$A.createComponents` to create the inner elements, an `Aura.Component[]` attribute to display the elements, and `component.getReference` to link controller actions to those components.